# Akka stream of Future messages returned in function

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a method defined below:

```
def requestingInformation(in: RequestA): Source[ResponseA, NotUsed] = {
  val a = actorB ? InputRequestA(in.requestId, in.info)
  val b = actorB ? InputRequestB(in.requestId, in.info)
  val c = actorB ? InputRequestC(in.requestId, in.info)

  val response = for {
    r1 <- a.mapTo[ResponseA]
    r2 <- b.mapTo[ResponseA]
    r3 <- c.mapTo[ResponseA]
  } yield List(r1, r2, r3)

  Source.future(response)
}
```

`Source.future(response)` is of type `Source[Future[List[ResponseA]]]` instead of `Source[Future[ResponseA]]`. I'm not sure if this is the correct way of using Akka Streams but I'm really stuck. I am looking for any inputs on how to send responses from three different `ask` patterns in a stream.

Answer (score 0):

To get a `Source[ResponseA, NotUsed]`, use [`mapConcat(identity)`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-cookbook.html#flattening-a-stream-of-sequences):

```
def requestingInformation(in: RequestA): Source[ResponseA, NotUsed] = {
  val a = actorB ? InputRequestA(in.requestId, in.info)
  val b = actorB ? InputRequestB(in.requestId, in.info)
  val c = actorB ? InputRequestC(in.requestId, in.info)

  val response = for {
    r1 <- a.mapTo[ResponseA]
    r2 <- b.mapTo[ResponseA]
    r3 <- c.mapTo[ResponseA]
  } yield List(r1, r2, r3)

  Source.future(response).mapConcat(identity)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be:

```
def requestingInformation(in: RequestA): Source[ResponseA, NotUsed] = {
  Source(List(
      InputRequestA(in.requestId, in.info),
      InputRequestB(in.requestId, in.info),
      InputRequestC(in.requestId, in.info)))
    .ask[ResponseA](actorB)
}
```

This will first create a Source with the 3 requests, and then use the 'ask' stream operator to send them to actorB and collect the 'ResponseA' replies.

See also https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/ask.html

Of course whether this is useful depends on what the rest of your application looks like ;)